# How to verify if LLVM "ret" instruction returns void?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, llvm, llvm-ir

I have the following snippet of code:

```
static LLVMContext TempContext;
Type * RetTy = Type::getVoidTy(TempContext)
for (Instruction *I : ListOfInstructions) {
  if (isa<ReturnInst>(I)) {
    RetTy = I->getOperand(0)->getType();
    break
  }
}
```

Where I am trying to capture the **RetTy of a instruction**, void or not, so I can use it on

```
getOrInsertFunction("TempF", FunctionType::get(RetTy, ArgsTys,false));
```

This code works as long as the ret instruction is not a `ret void`.

I tried to add a second `if` to check the `void` case, but this does not seem to work, and execution stops on the in the `FunctionType::get(...)` function, printing a back trace.

```
for (Instruction *I : ListOfInstructions) {
  if (isa<ReturnInst>(I)) {
    if ( I->getOperand(0)->getType() != Type::getVoidTy(TempContext)) {
      RetTy = I->getOperand(0)->getType();
      break
    }
  }
}
```

Note that removing the `for` loop all together works and execution continues, as the function `FunctionType::get(...)` handles the initialized `Type * RetTy = Type::getVoidTy(TempContext)` "void" value for `RetTy` just fine. But then I can't capture when a llvm function returns non-void values.

---

**How do I know when an instruction I is a return instruction and it is returning Void in LLVM IR?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your current code is that `ret void` does not have an operand, so calling `getOperand(0)` accesses invalid data.

Replacing your if with:

```
if (ReturnInst *ri = dyn_cast<ReturnInst>(I))
{
  if (ri->getNumOperands() == 0)
  {
    errs() << "VOID: " << *ri << "\n";
  }
  else
  {
    errs() << "NON-VOID: " << *ri << "\n";
  }
}
```

Now, this code will output `VOID:   ret void`, having correctly detected the instruction.

As an alternative, you could retrieve the return type for the function using any instruction by relying on instructions being contained by a function `I->getFunction()->getReturnType()`; however, this would assume that the function is well-formed and its ReturnInst matches its type and the instruction is part of a function.

Comment: I did not see this while reading the docs. Now, that you highlighted it, I see that `IRBuilder` calls `ReturnInst::Create` method that initializes a `TerminatorInst` (in InstrTypes.h) with `NumOps` argument set to 0. Thank you for the answer.